# Robot Framework and Browser support

Tags: selenium, robotframework

Has the robot framework support for IExplorer or only for Firefox and Chrome? (If yes, how to configure it?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From: [SeleniumLibrary documentation](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html).

Possible values for browser are all the values supported by Selenium and some aliases that are defined for convenience. The table below lists the aliases for most common supported browsers.

- firefox  FireFox
- ff           FireFox
- ie   Internet Explorer
- internetexplorer Internet Explorer
- safari   Safari
- googlechrome Google Chrome
- opera    Opera

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Selenium2Library`, which is much better than `SeleniumLibrary` so possible values for `browser` are as follows:

- firefox | FireFox
- ff | FireFox
- internetexplorer | Internet Explorer
- ie | Internet Explorer
- googlechrome | Google Chrome
- gc | Google Chrome
- chrome | Google Chrome
- opera | Opera
- phantomjs | PhantomJS
- htmlunit | HTMLUnit
- htmlunitwithjs | HTMLUnit with Javascipt support